# why i can't upgrade and manage my packages

Tags: command-line, upgrade, uninstall

why when i tried to upgrade or remove something this message comes in:

```
 "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem."
```

what should i have to do now?

Comment: run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as it is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and type as it says:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`